# jQuery .html rendering

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to render HTML in jQuery but it doesn't work. My PHP file :

```
if ( $lastTokens[0]['token'] <  $lastTokens[1]['token']) {
    $prixachat_format = '<i class="fas fa-arrow-up"></i>'.number_format($prixachat, 0, ',', ' ');
} elseif ($lastTokens[0]['token'] >  $lastTokens[1]['token']) {
    $prixachat_format = "<i class='fas fa-arrow-down'></i>".number_format($prixachat, 0, ',', ' '); 
} else {
    $prixachat_format = '<i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>'.number_format($prixachat, 0, ',', ' ');
}

$result = array(
        'token' => $prixachat_format,       
    );
wp_send_json($result);
```

My JS file:

```
jQuery.post(
    ajaxurl, {
        'action': 'get_token'
    },
    function(response) {
        jQuery('.update-token').html(response.token);       
    }
)
```

But it's still displayed as plain text? Any idea how to fix it ? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try .append() instead of .html()

```
jQuery.post(
    ajaxurl, {
        'action': 'get_token'
    },
    function(response) {
        jQuery('.update-token').append(response.token);       
    }
)
```